# Android - load more items when grid view has reached the end

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I'm making an app and I'm using grid view to show all of my images, the problem is I have lots of images, about 12,000, and I don't want to load all of them at the start, because lets face it, it will take forever, so I was wondering what is the best way of accessing the server to fetch more items once the gridview has reached the end.

Thanks.

Comment: you can use pagination based web service and use swipetorefreshlayout. what you have tried?

Comment: I want to use the grid view that android provides, im sure there is a way to do it with it

Comment: use universal image loader library or picasso with your gridview for image loading

Comment: Im using picasso but what does it matter, i dont want to fetch all of the data from the server at once...

Answer (score 2):

To achieve load more items on scrolled to end of the gridview

```
gridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener(){

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
                                 int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                                 int totalItemCount) {
                //Algorithm to check if the last item is visible or not
                final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                if(lastItem == totalItemCount){
                    // here you have reached end of list, load more data
                    fetchMoreItems();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,int scrollState) {
                //blank, not required in your case
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Pachu use fetchMoreItems() method to get items.

Comment: Use fetchMoreItems() method to add logic for getting items.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to start the server request for an image in the adapter `getView()`.  When the request completes, you set the retrieved bitmap on the `ImageView`.  There is a very in-depth description of this technique on the Android Developer Blog: [Multithreading For Performance | Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html). Most servers are fast enough that the lag time to display the image is not objectionable.

---

However, if you want to load images before the `ImageViews` are displayed, here's another way you can do it with an `OnScrollListener`, an `AsyncTask`, and a list adapter for the `GridView.

Say you have a constant `final int THRESHOLD = 50;` and a variable `lastItem` that starts at zero.

When user displays your `GridView` the `AsyncTask` kicks off and retrieves the first 100 images.  In the `onPostExecute()`, it adds the images to your adapter and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  It also adds 100 to `lastItem`.

So now your adapter has 100 images.  The user is scrolling through images and the `OnScrollListener` gets called.

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)

    if (firstVisibleItem >= lastItem - THRESHOLD) {
        new FetchImageAsyncTask().execute();
    }
}
```

Your `AsyncTask` executes, `lastItem` is updated to 200, and your adapter gets 100 more images.

Then the user scrolls some more and it starts all over again.

By using the threshold, the user can scroll another 50 images before the end of the list, and that may be enough time to load the next 100 images.